# Почему Leaflet карта не грузиться если аккордеон закрыт?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, openstreetmap, leafletjs

Использую [аккордеон из Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/expansion-panels) и пакет [nuxt-leaflet](https://github.com/schlunsen/nuxt-leaflet).

Если при загрузке страницы аккордеон не открывать сразу, то карта будет вот в таком виде:
[image]
Видно только часть, и при навигаций по другим частям карты, слой не грузится нормально.

Если же при загрузке страницы сразу открыть шаг с картой, то карта показываеться нормально:
[image]

Может кто-то объяснить почему так введёт себя загрузка карты? И как это исправить?

Comment: Хотите устроить шоу "Битва экстрасенсов", которые будут угадывать причину или всё-таки приведёте свой код?

Comment: @AK не добавил код сразу потому что компонент довольно большой. Вот компонент карты: https://gist.github.com/vodniciarv/833375255121d4e88510351e2c8e4682

Comment: в родительском компоненте подключаю компонент с картой так:
`'map-polygon': () => import('../components/products/MapPolygon.vue')`

Comment: Вы же наверное не раз читали правила сайта и знаете, что нужен минимально воспроизводимый пример и код нужно приводить в вопросе.

Comment: @AK https://jsfiddle.net/vodnicear/8a162res/5/